# How to launch SLComposeServiceViewController from another UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, ios8-share-extension, slcomposeviewcontroller

I have an iOS app with a Share Extension.

The main class of the Share Extension inherits the `SLComposeServiceViewController`, and in the Storyboard, I have checked *"Is initial view controller"*. However, I need another custom `view` to render with more options before eventually launching the Share Extension.

I added an additional `ViewController` in the Storyboard and added a button inside a container. This "Share" button should launch the original Share Extension, `Share View Controller Scene`

[image: Storyboard]

I added a `UIViewController` class, `ActionsMenuController`, and set that as a custom class for `Àction Menu Controller`.

```swift
class ActionMenuController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func launchShareExtension(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Somehow, I need to make the button's action function, `launchShareExtension`, switch scenes to the `Share View Controller`.

It seems as I should use segues to perform this, but I haven't found a way to define a segue identifier for my `Share View Controller`

Are there any other ways of launching a `ViewController` or `SLComposeServiceViewController`, or is there a way to achieve this using `segues`?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that adding a segue between a normal `UIViewController` and `SLComposeServiceViewController` can be done directly in the storyboard editor, but 
click+ctrl on the button and drag the appearing blue line to the Share View Controller Scene. A small segue option menu will appear, choose `show` which will launch and share extension and replace the action menu.

[image]

I found inspiration in this storyboard [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/464-storyboards-tutorial-for-ios-part-1)
about half way through. It covers the most basics in storyboard editing.